# OpenID connect provider, supporting HMAC not RSA, how to conform without jwks_uri?

Tags: openid-connect, jwk

I'm implementing an OpenID connect provider and I can't see anything in the spec that mandates a particular signing algorithm.  This means I should be able to just implement HMAC/HS256 and not bother with using certificates.  Is that right?

If so, why is jwks_uri mandatory in the metadata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid question I think.

The core spec [hints](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ServerMTI) that there might be situations that you don't *have* to:

> OPs MUST support signing ID Tokens with the RSA SHA-256 algorithm (an
>   alg value of RS256), unless the OP only supports returning ID Tokens
>   from the Token Endpoint (as is the case for the Authorization Code
>   Flow) and only allows Clients to register specifying none as the
>   requested ID Token signing algorithm.

But then the discovery document [goes on](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderMetadata) to contradict that by not allowing to advertise just `none` as an `id_token_signing_alg`:

> The algorithm RS256 MUST be included.

The latter, of course, does in turn justify having a required `jwks_uri`, but it feels odd.

Answer (score 1):

Discovery isn't required but if you do support it, the metadata document must include a `jwks_uri` and support RS256. IOW. you can support "none"-only without Discovery.